# How can I show all listed Todos?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am doing a project using Angular. I have a button called "ALL" by which I want to show all tasks. I wrote some scripts for this but it isn't showing any inputted value. Here I am adding my codes!

Typescript:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.css']
})
export class InputComponent {

  newTodo: string = '';
  savedTodo: string[] = [];

  save = () => {
    if(this.newTodo){
      for(var i = 0; i < this.savedTodo.length; i++){
      this.savedTodo[i]=this.newTodo;
      }
      console.log(this.newTodo)
      this.reset();
    }
  }

  reset = () => {
    this.newTodo = ''
  }


  allTodo = () => {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.savedTodo.length; i++){
    console.log(this.savedTodo[i]);
    }
  }

  activeTodo = () => {

  }

  completedTodo = () => {
    
  }
}
```

Here save() function helps to take input. and using allTodo() i am performing to show all todos.

HTML:

```
    <div>
        <mat-checkbox class="example-margin">0 item left</mat-checkbox>
        <mat-button-toggle-group>
            <mat-button-toggle (click)="allTodo()">ALL</mat-button-toggle>
            <mat-button-toggle (click)="activeTodo()">ACTIVE</mat-button-toggle>
            <mat-button-toggle (click)="completedTodo()">COMPLETED</mat-button-toggle>
        </mat-button-toggle-group>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is an Angular code instead of angularJs. Other hand newTodo is a string and isn't array.

Comment: @Beller can you tell me about typescript array declarations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your save function as

```
save = () => {
    if(this.newTodo.length){
      this.savedTodo.push(this.newTodo);
      console.log(this.newTodo)
      this.reset();
    }
  }
```